# Remove lines that do not match in bash

Tags: sed, grep

I've got a text file containing

```
Today, 12:34https://...
Today, 12:43https://...
Yesterday, 13:21https://...
Nottoday, 12:32https://
```

and would like to delete all lines that do not match with "Today" or "Yesterday".

I found a sed command here in this forum with only one pattern and tried out the following for a text file only containing Today lines:

```
sed -n '/Yesterday/p' file.txt
```

or

```
sed '/Yesterday/!d' file.txt
```

but it won't delete anything. Can you help me out how to eliminate all lines not containing "Today" or "Yesterday"?

Comment: Are you expecting the original file to change?

Comment: Try this with GNU sed:  `sed -E '/(Today|Yesterday)/!d' filename`

Comment: Yes, the original file should change and only contain lines with "Today" or "Yesterday" after the command. Sorry, didn't mention that.

Answer (score 2):

Sed does not modify your files (unless given the `-i` flag, for implementations that provide it). It reads the file and write to standard output, as can be seen below.

```
$ sed -n '/Yesterday/p' file.txt
Yesterday, 13:21https://...
$ cat file.txt
Today, 12:34https://...
Today, 12:43https://...
Yesterday, 13:21https://...
Nottoday, 12:32https://
```

To delete all lines not matching `Today` nor `Yesterday`, you can use the Ed editor.

```
printf '%s\n' 'v/Today\|Yesterday/d' w q | ed -s file.txt
```

`v` is the reverse global command, so `d` deletes all lines not matching `Today` or `Yesterday`. `w` writes the changes and `q` quits. The `-s` flag to Ed runs it in silent mode.

You can also use Sed with the `-i` flag,

```
sed -n -i '/Yesterday\|Today/p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To edit the file in place with `sed`, you need the non-standard `-i` option:

```
# GNU syntax à la perl (now also in busybox, NetBSD, OpenBSD):
sed -i -e /Yesterday/b -e /Today/b -e d your-file

# FreeBSD syntax (also in derivatives like macOS):
sed -i '' -e /Yesterday/b -e /Today/b -e d your-file
```

The `b` `sed` command `b`ranches out (equivalent of `next`/`continue` in some other languages), while `d` `d`eletes the pattern space (which ends up not being printed). So we delete all but the lines that either contain `Yesterday` or `Today`.

Or use `perl` (whose `-i` some `sed` implementations borrowed):

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /(Yester|To)day/' your-file
```

Standard *basic* regular expressions as used by `sed` or `ed` don't have a `|` alternation operator, however several `sed` implementations have a `-E` to switch to *extended* regular expressions (that option will also be in the next version of the POSIX specification for `sed` (not `ed`)).

```
sed -Ei '/(Yester|To)day/!d' your-file
```

The GNU implementation of `sed` also supports `\|` as an alternation operator in its basic regular expressions (without `-E`/`-r`):

```
sed -i '/\(Yester\|To\)day/!d' your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by 2 methods awk and python

command

```
 awk '!/Today|Yesterday/' filename
```

output

```
Nottoday, 12:32https:
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
h=re.compile(r'Today|Yesterday')
k=open('p','r')
for i in k:
    if not re.search(h,i):
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
Nottoday, 12:32https:
```

Comment: You have it the other way round. The lines with Today and Yesterday should be kept.